# Remove blank output being added by lazy method for reading big files

Tags: python, database, methods, whitespace, lazy-evaluation

I am using the Lazy Method for reading big files to get extract information from text files to store it on a database.

```
def read_in_chunks(file_object, chunk_size=1024):
"""Lazy function (generator) to read a file piece by piece.
Default chunk size: 1k."""
while True:
    data = file_object.read(chunk_size)
    if not data:
        break
    yield data


f = open('really_big_file.dat')
for piece in read_in_chunks(f):
    process_data(piece)
```

The problem is that if I modify the process_data(piece) to for example:

```
for data in piece:
    data = regex.findall(str(data)) 
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO table (Title) VALUES (?)', data)
```

I will get a blank space every time a new chunk is being read. In this case it is trivial to modify it to:

```
   for data in piece:
        data = regex.findall(str(data)) 
        if (data != ""):
             cursor.execute('INSERT INTO table (Title) VALUES (?)', data[1])
```

But in the information I am extracting there is some valid "blank spaces" (when there is not certain information in some fields. How can I avoid this blank space between chunks??? I know this is not a problem with the way I am extracting the information because if I extract smaller files without using the lazy method I don't have this problem. But I have certain files that are much bigger and it works really slow without the lazy method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of issues with what you have.  If you use findall, then *data* could be a list of strings.  That won't insert into the database very well like that.

The other issue is that the regex could be broken up between the chunks you're reading.  You want to look for the pattern, and then use any remainder text at the start of the next search.

try something like this:

```
left_over = ''
for piece in read_in_chunks(f):
    left_over += piece
    next_start = 0
    for m in regex.finditer(left_over):
        data = m.group(0)
        next_start = m.end() + 1
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO table (Title) VALUES (?)', data)
    left_over = left_over[next_start:]
```

Comment: Sorry about the first issue. I am using data[1] because the result that is inserted there in each iteration is the one I am interested on. (dirty, but works) In some cases the variable will be blank, which is correct. I will check out about the second thing you mention.

Comment: @sinnet3000:  That's a bit bizarre (that grabbing only the second match (data[1]) is what you want) - the only way I can see that working is if the files are composed of some sort of regular multiples of the chunk size you've chosen.  In general, that shouldn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

To complement @Gerrat's answer, here's an example of how `chunk_size` might be breaking your regular expression searching:

```
>>> from cStringIO import StringIO
>>> import re
>>> def chunker(f, chunk_size=10):
...     while True:
...         data = f.read(chunk_size)
...         if not data:
...             break
...         yield data
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{3}")
>>> text = "Abc123 def456 ----------   ghi789"
>>> # on the full dataset, it's fine
... pattern.findall(text)
['Abc123', 'def456', 'ghi789']
>>> # but on chunks ...
... for data in chunker(StringIO(text)):
...     print "data: %r" % data
...     print "matches: %r" % pattern.findall(data)
data: 'Abc123 def'
matches: ['Abc123']
data: '456 ------'
matches: []
data: '----   ghi'
matches: []
data: '789'
matches: []
```

Adding some intelligence to the chunker or processor as suggested would allow you to process things incrementally, but ensure none of the data records get inappropriately split.

Comment: Thanks for this, that made me clear what is happening over here.